# Overwrite Function using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm new to coding (and I'm not an IT or a techie guy in general) but I'm making a script that overrides the entry if it's a duplicate.

So I've already written a script that works perfectly fine. What it does is if I log something (like a transaction #) on the cells (in this example, A5:S5 row) and that transaction is done, I'll simply click a button and that entry will be moved from the current tab to Tab B last row.

However, these transactions tend to re-open, which means I'll have to log them again using the same transaction # and once done, I'll simply press a button and it will be moved to Tab B.

The issue here is that, while it successfully moves the logs to Tab B, it's added as another entry. It will not override the previous entry.

So the example code below is what I've written. As mentioned, it works perfectly fine in moving the contents of the row to TAB B.

But I don't know how I'm going to include the override method here. Like "if found duplicate, override".

```
var status = source.getRange('R6').getValues();
 var cStatus = source.getRange('E6').getValues();
 if (status=="Yes") {
   if (cStatus=="Done") {
     var sourceValues = dataToCopy.getValues();
     var lastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow();
     copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
     dataToCopy.clear({contentsOnly:true});
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Successful",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK)
   }
```

You have my many thanks.

Please see the examples below.

Picture A:
[I log the transaction. Since transaction is done, I click on Move button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xz2U.png)

[image]

Picture B:
[I click the button. Ticket is successfully logged/moved to Tab B.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Auk.png)

[image]

Picture C:
[Customer called in again with same transaction. New information has been given. I log the same transaction # and click the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9q3S.png)

[image]

Last picture:
[With my current coding, what happens is, it does this instead of overriding the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DORRj.png)

[image]

Comment: What would you do differently if you found the duplicate?

Comment: @Cooper just override them. For example, I had a transaction 1122 already logged and somehow the transaction opened again: I'll just simply log the same transaction (1122) with the new information, click the button and it should override the data in Tab B.

Comment: I don't understand did you add another line  to tab b and would not you have done so anyway?

Comment: If you can share a little of  the two tabs with examples on them without sharing private information

Comment: The purpose of Tab B is for dumping only. I have two tabs. Tab A where I log the transactions and I keep them in that tab if they have pending actions. Once done, I'll simply click a button in the Tab A that will move the transaction to Tab B. However, these transactions tend to re-open (meaning, customers get back) so I have to log them again in Tab A with an updated info. 

I'll update the info I shared again on the top and put sample pictures.

Comment: @Cooper the post has been updated with pictures as a way to visualize it.

Comment: So why do you have to know if there is another duplication transaction id in the Tab B?

Comment: I don't have to. Though, I would just like to set a pop-up button that says "There's an entry that has the same #. Would you like to proceed?" stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get your answer using this function. Your code would have to supply the transaction id  (tid)

```
function isthereaduplic(tid) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("TABB");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  return ~vs.indexOf(tid);
}
```